# Generate TSQL random dates between a range

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Generate 650 dates between 3rd Jan to 16th Jan 2023 and exclude weekends
and time between working hours i.e 9 AM to 5 PM

randomised to the day and right to milliseconds .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT TOP 1000
    DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000, DATEADD(MINUTE, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 480 + 540, 
    DATEADD(DAY, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 14, '2023-01-03 00:00:00'))) AS RandomDate
  FROM 
    sys.all_objects
)
SELECT 
 TOP 650 RandomDate
FROM 
  CTE
WHERE 
  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, RandomDate) NOT IN (1, 7) -- exclude weekends
  AND RandomDate BETWEEN '2023-01-03 09:00:00' AND '2023-01-16 17:00:00'
ORDER BY 
  RandomDate;
```

In this query, the DATEADD function is used three times to generate a random date and time between 3rd Jan 2023 and 16th Jan 2023 with a random milliseconds value. The first DATEADD call adds a random number of days (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 14) to 3rd Jan 2023, generating a random date between 3rd Jan 2023 and 16th Jan 2023. The second DATEADD call generates a random time between 9:00 AM and 5:00 PM by adding a random number of minutes (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 480 + 540) to the random date generated in the first DATEADD call. The third DATEADD call adds a random milliseconds value. The WHERE clause is then used to exclude weekends and to further restrict the random dates and times to only those between 9:00 AM and 5:00 PM on each date.